# Windows Media Player 12 Missing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I read that windows media player 12 is only available on windows 7.  That's fine, I have windows 7 Ultimate N.  So, I see this article on how to [enter link description here](http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/zanswers/2383)disable windows media player 12 which I'd like to use to *enable* WMP...only one problem, I can't see "Media Features" listed as an option in the control panel as described in the article.  Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an add-on for windows 7 N.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=31017ed3-166a-4c75-b90c-a6cef9b414c4&displaylang=en###

Comment: +1. The N version of Windows specifically excludes Media Player, so you won't find it in the Add Features dialogue.